# Spark SQL: Sqlite - Unparseable date

Tags: java, scala, sqlite, jdbc, apache-spark

I try to process a database with Apache Spark. But I get this *unparseable date exception*. I read all the other questions about this exception here on SO, but they don't help me. The interesing part of my code is this:

```
try {
  val tableData = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
                            .options(Map("url" -> databasePath,
                                         "dbtable" -> t))
                            .load()
  if (tableData.count > 0) {
    val df = tableData.show                    
  }

} catch {
  case s: SQLException => println("DEBUG, SKIPPING TABLE " + t)
  case e: Exception => println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT: " + t); System.exit(1)
}
```

So although I get `java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing date` I cannot catch this exception, it always takes the second case statement.

While catching the exception and just skipping the table would be a good start I am more interested in making it actually work. But I never call `Date.parse` manually so I don't know how to apply the answers from the other questions.

More output:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2009-01-01 00:00:00" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
```

Edit1: As requested, schema and example data:

```
CREATE TABLE [Invoice]
(
  [InvoiceId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  [CustomerId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  [InvoiceDate] DATETIME  NOT NULL,
  [BillingAddress] NVARCHAR(70),
  [BillingCity] NVARCHAR(40),
  [BillingState] NVARCHAR(40),
  [BillingCountry] NVARCHAR(40),
  [BillingPostalCode] NVARCHAR(10),
  [Total] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY  ([InvoiceId]),
  FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [Customer] ([CustomerId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

SELECT * FROM Invoice LIMIT 5;
1|2|2009-01-01 00:00:00|Theodor-Heuss-Straße 34|Stuttgart||Germany|70174|1.98
2|4|2009-01-02 00:00:00|Ullevålsveien 14|Oslo||Norway|0171|3.96
3|8|2009-01-03 00:00:00|Grétrystraat 63|Brussels||Belgium|1000|5.94
4|14|2009-01-06 00:00:00|8210 111 ST NW|Edmonton|AB|Canada|T6G 2C7|8.91
5|23|2009-01-11 00:00:00|69 Salem Street|Boston|MA|USA|2113|13.86
```

Edit2: I am running Spark 1.5.1. Further investigation lead me to this commit: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/d39f15ea2b8bed5342d2f8e3c1936f915c470783. The test cases clearly include the format which is used in my table. But this is a commit for Spark 1.6.0 and I first have to check all my dependecies if it is safe to update.

Comment: Could you show schema and example records? Does the problem persist if you remove `sqlMapFunc` and `show` / `collect`?  If not please include `sqlMapFunc` implementation. If it does please remove it from the question since it doesn't add anything.

Comment: sqlMapFunc is not the problem, I checked this. It's now replaced by a simple `.show`, the problem persists.

Comment: What happens if you change DateTime into a TimeStamp?

Comment: Timestamp seems to do the trick, at least I catch the execption now on another table (which also has Datetime columns)

Comment: Ok, I altered all those tables and now it works. BUT: Back to Q1 - How can I really catch this exception? (catching SQLException does not work, and catching Exception is too general) Because I don't want to alter every table, but to skip them (and maybe log a warning that the user should alter the table himself and resubmit it)

Comment: how about catching the exception in your output java.text.ParseException

Comment: Tried this, too, does not work.

Comment: I guess relying on exceptions is a post solution, have you thought about doing some pre etl checking? (such as loading in the data into a table where that field is a string and checking that the values are of a specific format which conforms to what you would expect?)

Comment: Alternatively see my answer below for configuring a UDF where you can have more control of that column and change the field type to string, and convert it into a format of your choosing.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I would open a new JIRA for that. For now you can handle this by manually casting date fields to string and using this as a subquery but it is not very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a UDF (user defined function) to format the date column for 2009-01-01 00:00:00 into a spark DateTime format, and then perform a sql query such as

sql("SELECT STRING_TO_DATE(column, 'inputformat', 'output format') FROM myrdd");

sql.collect();

```
  def string_to_date( time:String, inputFormat:String, outputFormat:String ) : java.sql.Timestamp = {
if (time == null)
{
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
}
// include some other checking for 'time' here

val dateParser = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat)
val date = dateParser.parse(time)
val dateFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat)
val format = dateFormatter.format(date)
val ticks = dateFormatter.parse(format)
val sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(ticks.getTime())
return sqlDate
```

}

sql.udf.register("STRING_TO_DATE", Utils.string_to_date _)